# Issue with facebook dialog builder

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to share a user's high score to facebook.

When the user presses the share button a screen pops up that shows the picture, description, and link that I would like to be posted to facebook.

However, when the post is actually posted to facebook only the link shows up. The picture and the description are missing.

Here is my code that sets the link, picture and description:

```
final FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
    .setLink("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nordquistproductions.robberducky&hl=en")
    .setPicture("https://lh6.ggpht.com/Y80j8m9tNKhwq8UfXtbS--pEb_1xfWv7YAxDDuY6euPQePdXCPRQ07vPl0ecTXpxxg=w300-rw")
    .setName(getString(R.string.facebookname))
    .setApplicationName(getString(R.string.app_name1))
    .setDescription(getString(R.string.facebookhighscoreshare)  + " " + highscore)
    .build();
```

Any ideas of why this might be happening?